# Cant scroll/swipe on touchscreen using dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I currently have dual monitors, of which one is a touchscreen. The touchscreen, an AOC e2239Fwt, is connected with a HDMI cable and USB. The other monitor, a Medion screen, is connected with a VGA cable.

My problem is that the touchscreen stops working when I try to scroll or swipe on it, although it does work fine if I don't do these two things. Then I have to reconnect the USB cable to make it work again. But also after the reconnect it still stops working when trying to scroll. The touch function does work as long as I don't scroll or swipe. As far as I know this problem came out of nowhere. I can't think of anything I've installed or done that might have caused this problem.

I recently found out that when I disconnect the non-touchscreen and reconnect the touchscreen, then the scroll and swipe function do work, even if I reconnect the non-touchscreen. But once I restart my computer, it doesn't work again.

I've installed the latest drivers of the screen and latest nvidia drivers, but this didn't help. I did also connect the non-touchscreen with a vga-dvi adaptor and I've reinstalled windows, but this didn't change a thing either.

I hope someone knows how to fix this problem,

Thanks.

P.S. Some information that might be relevant: I have a Medion MS-7616 with Windows 7 and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 240.